# cant get divs to display inline

Tags: html, css

Please see this pen for an example of my problem http://codepen.io/MarkRBM/pen/EmlJC

I cant get the 3 divs that say book now, subscribe, contact to display inline with the div with with the header and paragraph.  I have been trying for a while and looking at learn layout.com.  This is part of a larger project and I have tried to float it but it messes up the styling of everything else if I do that so I figured there must a way with inline block

edit  I have updated the pen with the full scss file the css in question is on lines 866-894.  There may be too much going wrong for you to figure it out and if so thats not a problem I will keep plugging away at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible, and you're on the right track. Just a few errors in the css:

First, `.locinfo` is `inline-block`, but it's inside `.loc`, which is not (so it's `block` by default) — so set `.loc` to `inline-block` as well.

You're also missing a semicolon after `inline-block` in the definition of `.locbook`, which is causing that rule to be ignored.

Without knowing exactly what you want the result to look like, I'm not sure if there's more that needs fixing. But those changes seem to get at least most of the way there.

---

Edit: more detail in response to comment:

`.locinfo` is alone by itself in its container, so set its width to 100% instead of 49%. The key is that this is the element's width as a percentage of *its container*. Its container (a `.loc`) has 49% of the page, so if you give `.locinfo` 49% of that, it will only have 24% of the page.

Similarly, set `.locbook` to 32%. Those three divs will then lie side-by-side in their container's 49% of the page.

Finally, set `vertical-align: top` on `.loc` and `margin: 0` on `.locbook`, and you'll get everything nicely aligned to the top.

Comment: Thanks that did work in my pen but not in my project, I have updated the pen with the full scss file the css in question is on lines 866-894.  There may be too much going wrong for you to figure it out and if so thats not a problem I will keep plugging away at it.

Comment: I've added more detail to get the blocks to all align to the top. Then I checked the codepen again and it contained all that new code... but hopefully my answer still holds in the context of the rest of the page. It seemed to fix all the problems on the more constrained example.

Comment: yeah thanks I should have created a new one instead of saving over it, you have helped I have it almost working as I want.  declaring the display:inline black is adding space to the top of the divs so I have to figure that out now but the inline part seems to be working.  thanks

Comment: Those `h1`s got a margin by default, and setting `margin: 0` got rid of the space when I tried it. Though maybe you're referring to something else. Anyway, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add semicolon after display:inline-block

```
.locbook{
  /*width: 49%;*/
  background-color: #3475b3;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try switching them to spans.  Div's are by default {display: block}, while spans are {display: inline}.  Block elements cannot be placed on the same line as other elements.  Inline elements' width cannot be specified however, in which case you'll want to style either div or span, whichever you choose (it doesn't really matter) to {display: inline-block}